# rename copy of result element

Tags: xml, xslt

What I need is to change the name of the element resulting of a xsl:copy-of.
What I’m doing right now is:

base xml:

```
<root>
  <element>
     <type>type</type>
     <value id="id">
        <first>first value</first>
        <under id="id_under"/>
     </value>
  </element>
</root>
```

Where element could be a collection, and also value could be a collection of elements.

My xslt:

```
<xsl:for-each select="root/element">
    <xsl:for-each select="value">
       <xsl:copy-of select="current()" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

With this I'm getting the following structure:

```
..
    <value id="id">
       <first>first value</first>
       <under id="id_under"/>
    </value>
..
```

this is an array of values, and that's Ok, that's exactly what I need. The only thing I need to transform here is the "value" tag name, and rename it for a variable I have already stored. How can I achieve that? if there is no way of renaming an "output" element of a copy-of, I guess that the only way would be create that in a template using xsl:element and attribute set with identity to get child elements? Am I right?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the element to be called something else, you don’t really want a `copy-of` it, do you?

```
<xsl:for-each select="value">
  <xsl:element name="$your-variable">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" /> <!-- copy the attributes -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="*" />  <!-- copy the child elements -->
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: mmm that's cool, I didn't know about select attribute on copy-of, thanks a lot, this is working for me.